# Heroku Deployment Issues with Postgres and Sequelize

Tags: postgresql, heroku, deployment, environment-variables, sequelize.js

I am trying to deploy my app to Heroku. It works perfectly fine when run locally. From the moment I deployed it (deploying through github integration) I received the generic Application Error screen. Below are my heroku logs. These actually run three times but there was no point in me posting the same thing three times. They always end with:

```
2017-05-02T14:59:26.033702+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=calm-crag-40902.herokuapp.com request_id=6b64883e-9697-4d58-84d9-2f173d5b4cb1 fwd="70.
54.76.222" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-05-02T14:59:27.425435+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=calm-crag-40902.herokuapp.com request_id=d3719d8f-4670-4621-a044-a511ee6884
10 fwd="70.54.76.222" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

This will print 2 to 4 times after each consecutive error screen. The first error is regarding the .env files not running and the second is trying to connect to sequelize. My primary focus is sorting out the .env because if that is sorted out, at least the app will show my app will be visible.

.env error:

```
{ Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '.env'
2017-05-02T16:09:39.622865+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Error (native)
2017-05-02T16:09:39.622866+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:641:18)
2017-05-02T16:09:39.622867+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:509:33)
2017-05-02T16:09:39.622867+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.config (/app/node_modules/dotenv/lib/main.js:30:37)
2017-05-02T16:09:39.622868+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/server.js:3:19)
2017-05-02T16:09:39.622869+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
2017-05-02T16:09:39.622869+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
2017-05-02T16:09:39.622870+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
2017-05-02T16:09:39.622871+00:00 app[web.1]:     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
2017-05-02T16:09:39.622871+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3) errno: -2, code: 'ENOENT', syscall: 'open', path: '.env' }
2017-05-02T16:09:40.242885+00:00 app[web.1]: Unhandled rejection
```

Sequelize error:

```
SequelizeConnectionRefusedError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
2017-05-02T16:09:40.242902+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/connection-manager.js:98:20
2017-05-02T16:09:40.242903+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Connection.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:186:5)
2017-05-02T16:09:40.242904+00:00 app[web.1]:     at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
2017-05-02T16:09:40.242905+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Connection.emit (events.js:188:7)
2017-05-02T16:09:40.242905+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:86:10)
2017-05-02T16:09:40.242906+00:00 app[web.1]:     at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
2017-05-02T16:09:40.242907+00:00 app[web.1]:     at emitErrorNT (net.js:1281:8)
2017-05-02T16:09:40.242907+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
2017-05-02T16:09:40.242909+00:00 app[web.1]:     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
2017-05-02T16:09:40.242908+00:00 app[web.1]:     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
2017-05-02T16:09:40.360035+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2017-05-02T16:09:40.373996+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

This is my index.js:

```
'use strict';

const fs        = require('fs');
const path      = require('path');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const basename  = path.basename(module.filename);
const env       = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const config    = require(__dirname + '/../config/config.json')[env];
const db        = {};

if (config.use_env_variable) {
  const sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable]);
} else {
  const sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
}

fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter((file) => {
    return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
  })
  .forEach((file) => {
    const model = sequelize['import'](path.join(__dirname, file));
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach((modelName) => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

config.json:

```
{
  "development": {
    "username": "",
    "password": "",
    "database": "late_file",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "postgres"
  },
  "test": {
    "username": "",
    "password": "",
    "database": "database_test",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "postgres"
  },
  "production": {
    "use_env_variable": "DATABASE_URL",
    "dialect": "postgres"
  }
}
```

.env, modified to exclude specific names of things

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_USER=
DB_PASS=
DB_NAME=
DB_SSL=true if heroku
DB_PORT=5432
DATABASE_URL=postgres://appropriate/url
```

applicable part of server.js

```
const pg = require('pg');

pg.defaults.ssl = true;
pg.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL, function(err, client) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('Connected to postgres! Getting schemas...');

  client
    .query('SELECT table_schema,table_name FROM information_schema.tables;')
    .on('row', function(row) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(row));
    });
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance for anyone who offers any support!

Answer (score 0):

Brandon,

I am running an app on Heroku using JAWS_DB and MySQL, but otherwise identical config.json and index.js.  In my case on Heroku, the "if (config.use_env_variable) {const sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable])" statement connects to the database without error. The logs appear to point to the "pg.connect" failing in server.js. It's not clear to me (without seeing the rest of your code) why you need to connect to the database in index.js, and then connect again in server.js. If you can remove the connection from pg.connect and try to run with just the connection from index.js it may stop this error.